# ¿Hay algún método en Java que permita devolver un redondeo a x número de decimales?

Tags: java

estaba buscando una forma de obtener números con dos decimales para esto:

```
System.out.println("Introduzca la tariafa por hora.");
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
float tarifaHoras = entrada.nextFloat();
        
System.out.println("Introduzca el número de horas trabajadas.");
Scanner entrada2 = new Scanner(System.in);
int numeroHoras = entrada.nextInt();
        
float totalCobro = tarifaHoras*numeroHoras;
        
System.out.println("El total a cobrar es:\n" + totalCobro);
```

El problema es que no encuentro ningún método que lo haga fácil, sin añadir líneas extra ni operaciones, algo parecido a como se hace en Python por dar un ejemplo:

```
x = round(5.76543, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directamente no hay ningún método que le pases el numero y a cuanto le quieras redondear, al menos que yo sepa. Lo que si hay son métodos de la librería Math, puedes llamarlos de manera estática a ambos.

- Para redondear según el criterio convencional (si es >=5 hacia arriba, <5 hacia abajo) tenemos `Math.round(totalCobro)` pero esto haría que redondease a un numero entero, para que lo hiciese a 2 decimales le tendrias que meter una simple operacion: `Math.round(totalCobro*100.0)/100.0`
- Para redondear para abajo el metodo seria Math.floor(totalCobro*100)/100
- Y para redondear hacia arriba Math.ceil(totalCobro*100)/100

Tambien le podrias dar formato a tu numero con `DecimalFormat` y seria tal que asi para redondear a dos decimales:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##"); 
System.out.println("El total a cobrar es:\n "+df.format(totalCobro));
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Muchas gracias :D